# How to override the CB LoginView in Django

Tags: python, django-views, django-urls

I have this url for my login. I'd like to have this login redirect to different pages depending the level of the user i.e admin or superuser.

How do I do it????

```
url(r'^login/$',  auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to overwrite get_success_url method on LoginView and create custom custom login.html file and swap default LoginView for your custom one

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView


class CustomLoginRedirectView(LoginView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_staff:
            return 'https://www.google.com/'
        else:
            return 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925589/how-to-override-the-cb-loginview-in-django'
```